# How to input n values in one line in python Provided n is decided by the user

Tags: python

Suppose the user decides he wants to input `n` integers.

How do we write code to accept `n` integers in the same line given `n` is decided by the user?

I know we can use `a, b = map(int,input().split())` but in this case I know 2 integers have to be inputted.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.Can you help me with my doubt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create a *list* of provided numbers:

```
numbers = [int(num) for num in input().split()]
```

How it works: the input string is split on whitespace, then the list comprehension creates a list of numbers by applying `int()` to each item.

Comment: Hello @eugene-yarmash, but what happend if the input is: 2 3 4 5, how can I deprecate the last 2 numbers?

Comment: @JoséAlonso Use `numbers = [int(num) for num in input().split()][:2]`

Answer (score 1):

You could just use an array:

```
numbers = map(int, input().split(' ')) #=> suppose input is '12 43 7'
print(list(numbers)) #=> [12, 43, 7]
```

Comment: i am getting the output-<map object at 0x000001E597EB29E8>

Comment: it works. can you tell me the data type of numbers before converting it to list?

Comment: there is just one problem i am facing right now. How do i relate the the input to the number n which is inputted by the user? i mean to say we can use numbers = map(int, input().split(' ')) for taking any number of inputs not just n number of inputs